# How to store one bit without the use of an IC?

Tags: non-volatile-memory, data-storage

I am trying to store a bit of data from a circuit, but I don't want to use an IC like an EEPROM chip. Is it possible to store one bit with a transistor or something else to that effect?

Comment: Battery and a flip flop.

Comment: Could build a single DRAM cell out of a MOSFET and a capacitor.

Comment: If you only need one, a latching relay. It's even non-volatile.

Comment: Just pretend that it isn't an EEPROM and use one because they are so tiny and cheap and, if you need to avoid detection it's easily hidden under a blob of epoxy.

Comment: @Andyaka Hollow out a a relay and glue it on top of it.

Comment: Good idea - nobody will notice and folk will be so impressed how many kB the relay can hold.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest latch requires two transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctoPi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED circuit on the right lets you see what's going on.

---

If you want non-volatile, that was covered before: [How to make 1 bit permanent memory circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/188314/11683)

Answer (score 1):

With relay comes this one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVfK5S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Or a latching relay if you can find one

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 2-transistor latch, crosscoupled, using 10 Meg ohm resistors and 1.5 volts battery.

The write time will be about 0.001 second (10Mohm, 10pf as primary internal timeconstant, with Miller effect as the major delay)