# Power ON-OFF Memory Logic Circuit

Tags: logic-gates, touch

There is touch sense circuit that controls a SMPS circuit drives a power LED at output.  When disconnect the energy while LED ON, if I reconnect the energy LED must start be as ON state. I need a cheap, logic circuit. Thank you for your help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmB3ye.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a simple referance design. Touch IC'output state is initially active high, because of them there is a NOT circuit made by NPN.
Circuit should save ON state at least 30 minutes.

U2 is [IQS127D](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/42/iqs127_datasheet-7419.pdf)

Comment: What you need is some form of nonvolatile memory, not merely a logic circuit.  This could be anything from an EEPROM or flash to a latching relay.  Do you have any preferences?

Comment: I thought there should be a logic circuit which drives a capacitor somehow. That capacitor should have large discharge time  so that it should provide enough voltage to output left high in case of reconnecting. @CristobolPolychronopolis

Comment: Do you have a requirement to guarantee that the state is preserved for a specific amount of time (undetermined thereafter)?  If so, what's the time constraint?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis It should be min. 5 min.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make 1 bit permanent memory circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/188314/how-to-make-1-bit-permanent-memory-circuit)

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, but I won't use 555 to control button. I have touch sense IC that gives toggled output according to touch input. I want to combine that memory circuit with my touch sense ckt.

Comment: If you want to make the memory in an existing circuit nonvolatile, you need to show us the circuit!

Comment: @DaveTweed Dave nonvolatile circuit is not define my requirement exactly. We can say time-limited memory. This circuit should save high state at least 5 min.

Comment: Unless you also specify a maximum time, we have to assume that it's arbitrarily large -- nonvolatile.

Comment: @DaveTweed Dave I specified max. time as 5 minutes, but customer changed as at least 30 min.

Comment: "At least" is a minimum time. not a maximum time. You also need to tell us what "U2" actually is.

Comment: @DaveTweed IQS127D00008 Touch IC toggles output between GND-VDD+0.3V with respect to input. Sorry, there is no limit for max. time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a circuit using a ratchet relay.

[image]

Comment: This type of circuit is not suitable for my design.

Answer (score 0):

Maxim has an app note on this subject that seems a bit overkill but here ya go:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/4/4624.html